# How to detokenize Protein Embedding Method

Tags: python, biopython, embedding

I'm using `ProtTransBertBFDEmbedder` embedding to covert my sequence into embedding format.
It returns me an array (length: 1024). My purpose is how can I find the original sequence again by using this 1024-length array. So how can I **detokenize/reverse** it?

```
!pip3 install -U bio_embeddings[all] > /dev/null

from bio_embeddings.embed import ProtTransBertBFDEmbedder

embedder_bertbfd = ProtTransBertBFDEmbedder()

embedding = embedder_bertbfd.embed("YSPNNIQHFHEEHLVHFVL")
reduce_per_protein = embedder_bertbfd.reduce_per_protein(embedding)

print(reduce_per_protein)


print(reduce_per_protein.shape)
```

> Output (1024,)

How can I get this original sequence (`YSPNNIQHFHEEHLVHFVL`) again by using `reduce_per_protein`

You can use this [Original Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/sacdallago/bio_embeddings/blob/develop/notebooks/goPredSim.ipynb) to try

Comment: Have you tried the extract methods? https://docs.bioembeddings.com/v0.1.6/api/bio_embeddings.extract.html

Comment: First time I saw this. I haven't tried it before but I don't know how to try.

Comment: Just guessing bio_embeddings.extract.BasicAnnotationExtractor(reduce_per_protein) ? I do not have this biology domain knowledge you probably have to ask someone on the biology steckexchange what the opposite of embedd is?

Comment: I hoped that this was generated through any VAE, & there should be a little hidden decoder, had been used for training, somewhere in GitHub. However, as it is specified [here](http://doi.org/10.1101/2020.07.12.199554), they use a transformer as an encoder, so there is no easy way to decode original sequence but training your own decoder-model.

Comment: @Vovin Great point. I also read the original paper you mentioned for embedding but there is a point I don't understand. If this embedding method does not have a decoder, how do they evaluate the deep learning models developed using this embedding method? because some people are using this method on the data they are trying to predict. You cannot evaluate the model without a detokenize method.

Comment: @drorhun As I understood this, they trained sequences against their features. BERT & its siblings as encoders & simple feed forward networks as analysers. BERT & others are pretrained models, so original versions were just fine-tuned for protein-specific tasks.

Comment: @dosas or anyone else, please turn your comments into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BasicAnnotationExtractor()` from `bio_embeddings.extract` module to achieve the desired result as follows:

```
from bio_embeddings.extract import BasicAnnotationExtractor

print(BasicAnnotationExtractor(reduced_embedding))
```

Also, you must notice that you need to define your custom model architecture. If not you may run into some issues with its execution.

Comment: Thank you @Cardstdani. As you mentioned, I am getting an error like `You first need to define your custom model architecture.` I couldn't find the solution in anywhere. Do you know what is that mean?

Comment: @drorhun unfortunately, I still looking at documentation pages without results. But I think it's related to the model used to perform the embedding. That is, you need to define in some way explicitly the model that the module uses, but I didn't find the way

Comment: BasicAnnotationExtractor has 4 functions. `get_subcellular_location` , `get_secondary_structure`, `get_annotations`, and `_class2label`. I defined a extractor based on init function like `my_extractor = BasicAnnotationExtractor("bert_from_publication")` then I tried to run some functions of BasicAnnotationExtractor. For example, `my_extractor.get_secondary_structure(reduced_embedding)`. but I am getting an error

Comment: @drorhun I have tried to convert the embedded string to a `numpy.ndarray` and failed completely as it requests integer values. So I guess reversing from embedding to string is not possible with `bio_embeddings`, according to the documentation found.  I would suggest to switch to another library that supports both embedding and reversing.